# Changing position of output Stream

Tags: c#, file, stream

I need to change the position from the end to the beginning of the header written to output stream, Is there any better way to do this

```
outputStream.Write(header, 0, header.Length);
outputStream.Position = outputStream.Position - header.legnth;
```

Comment: When you've been written `header`, the `outputStream` **is** at the end of the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 outputStream.Write(header, 0, header.Length);
```

will move the position of stream to the end of the header,

```
outputStream.Seek(header.Length, SeekOrigin.End);
```

The above Seek will move the position of the stream to the beginning.Suppose, header length is 2 bytes. You've been written 2 bytes, and then Seek moves the position 2 bytes backwards.

Comment: `SeekOrigin.End` seem to be somewhat strange... Also there are file formats that put header at the end... You may want to add clarification why you suggesting it instead of `Begin`.

Comment: Your code will position the stream at the **beginning** of the header. Suppose, `header` length is 2 bytes. You've been written 2 bytes, and then `Seek` moves the position 2 bytes backwards.

Comment: @JeevaMahendran: please, look at my comment to the question. Either question is incorrect, or OP doesn't understand, how `Stream` works. The first, your edited answer assumes, that there's nothing in the stream already. Well, may be... since the question about some `header`. But the second, this is unnecessary action - the stream is already positioned at the end of the header (which is coincides with the end of the stream at the moment).

Comment: @Dennis:when I first saw the question, i knew that the position will be pointing the end when the header is written,I thought may be he needs to point the beginning and added outputStream.Seek(header.Length, SeekOrigin.End);. question was not clear, I guess he wants to move the header to the beginning after writing the header.

Comment: Please edit you post to explain what exact case you answering. Despite being accepted answer it does not mean it is ok to require future readers to scan comments (that could be also deleted without any trace). Without good explanation `End` with positive offset looks wrong - it should be either negative offset, or possibly `Current` with negative offset if you don't like usage of `Position`.